# why nginx rewrite not working for video wilth protect from direct links?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, jwplayer

Somedays ago, on my server appeared error: video not found or access denied. The path are correct. I play video by jwplayer.
And i have a file protection from direct links.

```
location /route/ {
                    include /home/username/shop/route/route.conf;

            }
```

in route.conf:

```
rewrite ^/route/9be25319f8164b5dacd481f700b3e69d/93/video.flv$ /media/courses/video1.flv;
```

Why it dont working?

full server config:

```
     user nginx nginx;
     worker_processes 3;

     error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log info;

     events {
         worker_connections  1024;
         use epoll;
     }

     http {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format main
            '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
            '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
            '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
            '"$gzip_ratio"';

    client_header_timeout 10m;
    client_body_timeout 120m;
    send_timeout 120m;

    connection_pool_size 256;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 2k;
    request_pool_size 4k;

    gzip off;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 4 8k;
    gzip_types text/plain;
     output_buffers 1 32k;
    postpone_output 1460;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    keepalive_timeout 75 20;

    ignore_invalid_headers on;

    index index.html;
    server {
            listen X.X.X.X:80;
            server_name mysite.com;

            access_log /home/user/logs/nginx-access.log;
            error_log /home/user/logs/nginx-error.log;

            location /static/ {
                    alias /home/user/shop/static/;

            }
            location /media/ {
                    alias /home/user/shop/media/;

            }
            location /route/ {
                    include /home/shamprod/shop/route/route.conf;

            }
            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888/;
                    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
            }


    }
```

Comment: Please provide an example link to where it is not working, thanks.

Comment: Please, provide full server config

Comment: this link dont work /route/9be25319f8164b5dacd481f700b3e69d/93/video.flv

Comment: @AlexeyTen the full server config i added in question.

Comment: The problem was solwed by server reboot!